# Jmeter: Javascript variable not returning any value

Tags: javascript, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

I am using one Javascript function to generate a random Number.

Used a User Parameter(Preprocessor) under the request

Added a Variable: `farmeid`

Function: `${__javaScript('bam-'+parseInt((Math.random()*1000000),10))}`

When I am using the varialble `${frameid}`, it is returning no Value.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there is a comma in your expression here: `),10` which acts as a delimiter for function parameters. If you can remove this `,10` bit so your expression could look like:

```
${__javaScript('bam-'+parseInt(Math.random()*1000000),)}
```

This would be successfully evaluated by __javaScript function.

If this `10` bit is a must you can use [BSF PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_PreProcessor) with the following code:

```
vars.put("frameid",'bam-'+parseInt((Math.random()*1000000),10));
```

And the easiest way is using [__Random](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/64307-using-jmeter-functions-part-ii) function like

```
bam-${__Random(111111,999999,)}
```

directly where it's required.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use Jmeter's Random Variable generator.
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Variable

Cheers,